# installing telegram bot api package failed

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot, go-modules, go-get

I'm trying to install telegram bot api module for golang from this link:
https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api

the installation example that showed there isnt working and raises the next error:

```
cannot find package "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/foo/go/src/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5 (from $GOPATH)
```

I looked on google and I saw some people recommending use "go install", but that raises the same error.

I would like to some help here, I'm trying figuring this out without a success for a while now. and feel free to ask for any further infotmation if you need

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the repo, you're trying to `go install` a _module_. The repo doesn't have a `main` package, so it's not supposed to be compiled to a standalone binary. The example in the readme would be something you write, and you import the package using `go get` (not `go install`). Then you can `go install` the main package _you_ wrote.

Answer (score 0):

So to elaborate on my comment:

The package you're trying to use is a module. It has no `main` function (or `main` package). The example in the readme file is something you would write yourself. Say you want to call it *"mybot"*, you'd go about it something like this:

```
$ mkdir mybot
$ go mod init github.com/yourname/mybot
$ go get -u github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5
$ vim main.go
```

In this `main.go` you can paste the example, then run:

```
$ go build .
```

It'll generate a binary in the current directory called `mybot`. You can run this like any executable:

```
$ ./mybot
```

Once you're up and running, install it using `go install .`. This will put the binary in `$GOPATH/bin`. If you added that to your `$PATH` variable, you can just run the binary by running `mybot` from anywhere...